# Multiple images in RadTreeView

Tags: telerik, radtreeview

In a Telerik RadTreeView has anyone ever been able to display multiple images on the RadTreeNode? RadTreeNode has the .ImageURL property, but just sets one image. It would be usedfull to display a couple of images, or another image after the node text.

I'm using RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax Q3 2010

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple the images in front of the treeview nodes with templates (check [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx)) - thus you can have as many images as you want for the nodes.

Comment: I also added controls on the server side by doing node.Controls.Add()